# Python: Serialização de classes namedtuple em json

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import json
from collection import namedtuple


class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def tojson(self):
        return json.dumps(self.__dict__)
```

Olá pessoal, desenvolvi a solução acima para transformar uma class em json.

Sei que o **__dict__** não existe no namedtuple, e que é possível evocar o metodo **_asdict()** para substituí-lo.

```
Emp = namedtuple('Emp', 'name age')
a = Emp('Luc', 10)
json.dumps(a._asdict())
```

Como posso criar um metodo na classe namedtuple para assumir a função equivalente tojson? tentei do modo abaixo e não funciona... :/

```
Emp.tojson = json.dumps(Emp._asdict()) #error
```

Trecho em execução no ideone: https://ideone.com/6VaFDN

Comment: Qual é o erro ?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/brito/projetos/00-incolumepy/incolumepy/testes/handler_files/json/namedtuple2json00.py", line 5, in <module>
    Emp.tojson = json.dumps(Emp._asdict())
TypeError: _asdict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: O que voce pode fazer é uma subclasse da namedtuple e ali criar a função mas eu não recomendaria isso, o trabalho que teria seria grande. O que de fato você está querendo fazer?
Vide o link em ingles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44320382/subclassing-python-namedtuple

Comment: @Onilol, eu quero acrescentar o metodo tojson no objeto namedtuple.

Comment: E por quê precisa de um método para isso? Não bastaria fazer [`json.dumps(a)`](https://repl.it/@acwoss/CrookedWearyBoolean)?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, Na pratica preciso do objeto para simplificar algumas tarefas, mas sem implementar uma classe para isto. Onde a utilização de dicionários em vez de objetos, seria demasiadamente complexa.

Comment: Mas dessa maneira você teria o objeto, não apenas um dicionário.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apesar de desaconselhar esta prática, o que você quer fazer pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

```
Emp.tojson = lambda self: json.dumps(self._asdict())
```

Comment: Porque é desaconselhavel?

Comment: Olhe a trabalheira que teria: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738987/extension-method-for-python-built-in-types , alem de não poder alterar tipos padrão.

Comment: Na pratica preciso do objeto para simplificar algumas tarefas, mas sem implementar uma classe para isto. Onde a utilização de dicionários em vez de objetos, seria demasiadamente complexa.

Comment: Recomendo que olhe esse link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44320382/subclassing-python-namedtuple